# Narrowing conversions and initializer lists, which compiler is right?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, c++11, clang

Considering the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int {
  double x(7.0);
  int i{x};
  std::cout << "i = " << x << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

---

- When compiled in GCC4.9 it compiles fine with only a warning:

  > > `warning: narrowing conversion of ‘x’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { }`

- Compiling with either Clang3.3 or VC++2013 gives a compile error:

  > > `error: type 'double' cannot be narrowed to 'int' in initializer list`
  > >     `error C2397: conversion from 'double' to 'int' requires a narrowing`

---

### Questions:

- Which of the compilers is right according to the standard?
- Is there any reason why the compilers mentioned above should exhibit such diverse behaviour?

Comment: Note that GCC user to emit an error for this code (I don't remember when exactly this behaviour changed.)

Comment: GCC 4.6 gives an error, it was downgraded to a "pedwarn" for GCC 4.7 for [PR 49793](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49793) so now it's a warning, enabled by default, and can be made into an error with `-pedantic-errors` or `-Werror=narrowing`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### The answer

Both compilers are correct!

---

#### Explanation

The Standard doesn't distinguish between an *error* and a *warning*, both go under the category of *Diagnostics*.

> `1.3.6` **diagnostic message** `[defns.diagnostic]`
>
> > message belonging to an implementation-defined subset of the implementation's output messages

Since the Standard says that a diagnostic is required in case a program is ill-formed, such as when a narrowing-conversion takes place inside a braced-initializer, both compilers are confirming.

Even if the program is ill-formed from the Standards point of view, it doesn't mandate that a compiler halts compilation because of that; an implementation is free to do whatever it wants, as long as it issues a diagnostic.

---

---

#### The reason for gcc's behavior?

Helpful information was provided by [@Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely) through comments on this post, below are a merge of the two comments;

> *he exact reason is that GCC made it an error at one point and it broke ALL THE PROGRAMS so it got turned into a warning instead. Several people who turned on the `-std=c++0x` option for large C++03 codebases found harmless narrowing conversions to cause most of the porting work to go to C++11
>
> See e.g. [PR 50810](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50810) where Alisdair reports narrowing errors were >95% of the problems in Bloomberg's code base.
>
> In that same PR you can see that unfortunately it wasn't a case of "let's just issue a warning and be done with it" because it took a lot of fiddling to get the right behaviour.*

Comment: +1 The exact reason is that GCC made it an error at one point and it broke **ALL THE PROGRAMS** so it got turned into a warning instead. Several people who turned on the `-std=c++0x` option for large C++03 codebases found harmless narrowing conversions to cause most of the porting work to go to C++11, e.g. `for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) char c[] = { 'f', 'o', 'o', '0' + i , '\0' };` where the value never goes out of range, but is technically a narrowing conversion

Comment: I thought one had to be wrong! - Sweet answer, and I really like the quote from imaginary guy!

Comment: See e.g. [PR 50810](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50810) where Alisdair reports narrowing errors were >95% of the problems in Bloomberg's code base (and in that same PR you can see that unfortunately it wasn't a case of _"let's just issue a warning and be done with it"_ because it took a lot of fiddling to get the right behaviour)